Are there any networks where, when you start an application, everyone knows that you have joined?
I mean for example:
Business app in which all are client and server and It's P2P connection between.
But When you start app your partners and you without Enter Ip:Port, Host... already know that appeared new partner? If you are not know, Please share me your ideas how I can implement it?
I mean ideas how partners can find new partner.)

You could look at multicast..
